# The powerprofile and systrace outputs are not consistent

Tags: android, energy, cpu-cores, systrace, consumption

I'm generating the PowerProflie file and the Systrace file to get the energy consumption of an
Android Application, but I found that the number of cpu cores is different between the two files.

I'm using this command line for Systrace:

```
command = "python " + platformToolsFolder + "/systrace/systrace.py --time=" + this.timeCapturing + " freq idle -o " + this.systraceFilename;
```

and for PowerProfile :

```
this.executeCommand("java -jar apktool_2.2.2.jar if framework-res.apk", null);
this.executeCommand("java -jar apktool_2.2.2.jar d framework-res.apk", null);
this.executeCommand("mv " + jarDirectory + "/framework-res/res/xml/power_profile.xml " + outputLocation, null);
```

this is a part of the PowerProfile file I've got :

```
  <item name="radio.active">320</item>
<item name="radio.scanning">5.8</item>
<array name="radio.on">
    <value>5.8</value>
    <value>5.8</value>
</array>
<item name="modem.controller.idle">5.8</item>
<item name="modem.controller.rx">226</item>
<item name="modem.controller.tx">226</item>
<item name="modem.controller.voltage">4.0</item>
<array name="cpu.clusters.cores">
    <value>4</value>
</array>
<array name="cpu.speeds.cluster0">
    <value>850000</value>
    <value>918000</value>
    <value>987000</value>
    <value>1056000</value>
    <value>1125000</value>
    <value>1216000</value>
    <value>1308000</value>
    <value>1400000</value>
    <value>1466000</value>
    <value>1533000</value>
    <value>1633000</value>
    <value>1700000</value>
    <value>1767000</value>
    <value>1834000</value>
    <value>1917000</value>
    <value>2001000</value>
</array>
<array name="cpu.active.cluster0">
    <value>9.3</value>
    <value>9.3</value>
    <value>10.6</value>
    <value>11.6</value>
    <value>13.3</value>
    <value>15.0</value>
    <value>17.2</value>
    <value>20.2</value>
    <value>22.8</value>
    <value>26.3</value>
    <value>27.4</value>
    <value>29.7</value>
    <value>30.2</value>
    <value>32.1</value>
    <value>33.9</value>
    <value>38.5</value>
</array>
<item name="cpu.idle">4.1</item>
<array name="memory.bandwidths">
    <value>1.3</value>
</array>
<item name="battery.capacity">3500</item>
<item name="wifi.controller.idle">4.9</item>
<item name="wifi.controller.rx">72.3</item>
<item name="wifi.controller.tx">72.3</item>
<array name="wifi.controller.tx_levels" />
<item name="wifi.controller.voltage">4.0</item>
<array name="wifi.batchedscan">
    <value>64.2</value>
    <value>64.2</value>
    <value>64.2</value>
    <value>64.2</value>
    <value>64.2</value>
</array>
```

and this is a part of my Systrace file :

```
      <idle>-0     (-----) [002] d..1 51825.602557: cpu_idle: state=4294967295 cpu_id=2
      <idle>-0     (-----) [002] d..1 51825.602791: cpu_idle: state=1 cpu_id=2
      <idle>-0     (-----) [006] d..1 51825.602869: cpu_idle: state=4294967295 cpu_id=6
      <idle>-0     (-----) [005] dn.1 51825.602907: cpu_idle: state=4294967295 cpu_id=5
      <idle>-0     (-----) [006] d..1 51825.602915: cpu_idle: state=0 cpu_id=6
  ipi_cpu_dvfs_rt-251   (  251) [005] .... 51825.602942: cpu_frequency: state=900000 cpu_id=0
      <idle>-0     (-----) [004] dn.1 51825.602989: cpu_idle: state=4294967295 cpu_id=4
  ipi_cpu_dvfs_rt-251   (  251) [005] .... 51825.602994: cpu_frequency: state=900000 cpu_id=1
  ipi_cpu_dvfs_rt-251   (  251) [005] .... 51825.603000: cpu_frequency: state=900000 cpu_id=2
  ipi_cpu_dvfs_rt-251   (  251) [005] .... 51825.603003: cpu_frequency: state=900000 cpu_id=3
      <idle>-0     (-----) [005] d..1 51825.603034: cpu_idle: state=0 cpu_id=5
      <idle>-0     (-----) [004] d..1 51825.603100: cpu_idle: state=0 cpu_id=4
      <idle>-0     (-----) [004] d..1 51825.607831: cpu_idle: state=4294967295 cpu_id=4
      <idle>-0     (-----) [005] dn.1 51825.608429: cpu_idle: state=4294967295 cpu_id=5
      <idle>-0     (-----) [006] dn.1 51825.608549: cpu_idle: state=4294967295 cpu_id=6
      <idle>-0     (-----) [005] d..1 51825.608610: cpu_idle: state=0 cpu_id=5
      <idle>-0     (-----) [005] d..1 51825.608615: cpu_idle: state=4294967295 cpu_id=5
      <idle>-0     (-----) [005] d..1 51825.608618: cpu_idle: state=0 cpu_id=5
      <idle>-0     (-----) [006] d..1 51825.608654: cpu_idle: state=0 cpu_id=6
      <idle>-0     (-----) [004] d..1 51825.608688: cpu_idle: state=1 cpu_id=4
      <idle>-0     (-----) [006] d..1 51825.608974: cpu_idle: state=4294967295 cpu_id=6
      <idle>-0     (-----) [005] dn.1 51825.609108: cpu_idle: state=4294967295 cpu_id=5
      <idle>-0     (-----) [006] d..1 51825.609129: cpu_idle: state=0 cpu_id=6
      <idle>-0     (-----) [005] d..1 51825.609136: cpu_idle: state=0 cpu_id=5
      <idle>-0     (-----) [007] d..1 51825.610061: cpu_idle: state=4294967295 cpu_id=7
```

As you can see in the power profile file I have 4 cpu cores (cpu.clusters.cores=4) but in Systrace file I have 8 cpu cores (cpu_id=0-7)
and most of cpu frequencies (cpu_frequency) in Systrace file doesn't exist in powerprofile file (cpu.speeds.cluster0) so I can't get the energy consumed,
Please let me know if you have any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Systrace is likely right here in terms of CPU core count. You can run `adb shell ls /sys/devices/system/cpu` to see how many cores there are on your device.

power_profile.xml is provided by OEMs so the values may be off. `cpu.clusters.cores` shows CPU cores in clusters (modern mobile devices have big/small cores) so for a typical 8 core device, it should look like this:

```
<array name="cpu.clusters.cores">
    <value>4</value>
    <value>4</value>
</array>
```

Looks like only values for the first cluster is provided in your power_profile.xml.

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes I have 8 cores on my device, so is there any way to correct my power_profile.xml  ?

Comment: I'm afraid you might have to contact the device OEM to correct that file...